# Why different behaviors between running Python module as an executable vs. Python [filename]

Tags: python

So, I created a simple python module, test.py

```
import commands

def main():
  cmd = 'ls -l'
  (status, output) = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
  print status, output

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

When I ran it using "Python test.py", I got the result that I expected. But when I ran it as an executable (yes, it has the 'x' permission), the program didn't respond at all and I had to Ctrl+C to quit it. Why is that? Shouldn't both ways give the same result?

Comment: Is #!/usr/bin/python the first line of your script?  If in windows it should be something like #!C:\\[python_dir]\python.exe I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a hash-bang line to the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import commands
...
```

This tells your system what interpreter to use to execute the script. Without it it doesn't know if it's a shell script, Perl script, Python script, what.

Answer (score 2):

You need the [hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) to be the first line of your script, referencing the path of the Python interpreter. Otherwise, all the OS knows is that you're trying to execute a script, and it has no idea how to go about doing that.

Comment: in fact it doesn't even know that it is a script. It could be any kind of thing that is executable.